# cos (arc csc (x+3)/4)

Tags: trigonometry

Write the expression as an equivalent algebraic expression involving only x. (Assume x is positive.)

Here is my work:

(arc csc((x+3)/4)

let theta = arcsin 4/(x+3)

sintheta = 4/(x+3)

Then I made a triangle and solved for the adjacent side and got (x-1)

So my answer was cos (x-1)/(x+3)

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \dfrac{x+3}{4}$, and $\theta = \csc^{-1}(y) \to \csc \theta = y \to \sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{y} = \dfrac{4}{x+3} \to \sin^2\theta = \dfrac{16}{(x+3)^2} \to \cos^2 \theta = 1-\dfrac{16}{(x+3)^2} = \dfrac{x^2+6x-7}{(x+3)^2} \to \cos \theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+6x-7}}{|x+3|}$

Answer (score 0):

if $\csc \theta = \frac{x+3}4$ then
$$
\sin \theta = \frac4{x+3}
$$
so
$$
\theta = \arcsin\frac4{x+3}
$$

but for any $z$ we have
$$
\cos \arcsin z = \sqrt{1-z^2}
$$
can you combine these two pieces of information to get your answer?